# can't find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1

Tags: android, build.gradle

I was working on some projects I downloaded from GitHub, I remember when I open one of these Projects I got a message saying `upgrade your grade` or something like that and I pressed Upgrade every time I got this message. After I've done from what I was doing, when I try to create a new project I get this message:

```
ERROR: Could not find calm. android. tools. build: grade: 3.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
```

When I try to put these URLs into the browser I got a message 404 for the last two URLs.
I tried many solutions from stack overflow and GitHub, but none of them worked out for me
I tried to delete android studio and Gradle files, I tried `invalidate caches` and I also tried to change the gradle version

Comment: Are you able to download the pom file clicking the link posted in the question?

Comment: yes but not the others

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to add `google()` repo in your project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //Add this repo
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //Add this repo
    }
}
```

Comment: Google repo is added since gradle is looking at  *https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/*

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // <--- Add this
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // <--- Add this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the page with all Gradle distributions so far: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Because other solutions didn't work for me I'd to bruteforce a URL in my gradle-wrapper.properties like this:

```
#Wed Oct 30 14:54:00 BRT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Notice the `\` after `https`. This is mandatory on Android Studio, as far as I could learn to use this aproach.

Comment: The question is about the android gradle plugin, not gradle distribution.

Comment: Well, if the answer is not usefull to OP, he can let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: there is no different between this and my config and it also didn't work